# Power View - Tables with columns of the similar data

Tags: plot, powerpivot, powerview

Apologies in advance if my question is obvious but I'm new to this and having spent days searching and experimenting I cannot achieve the result I'm after.

I have a big table of data that I want to plot some graphs for, namely stacked columns and then filter these using other criteria such as date. I came across Power View and have been learning to use it hoping it will let me produce the reports I'm after rather than standard Excel graphs which are very clunky.

An example of the sort of data my tables contains is as follows although I have a lot of other columns and about 20 of the similar metric columns:

[image: [Example of data structure]]

And this is the sort of graph I want to plot:
[image: [Stacked column]]

Where the red sections correspond to "R0" values, the orange "R1" and the green "R2" - they're essentially a rating; poor, ok and good. I can plot a single metric versus the items column with the stacked bar fine but cannot find a way to plot the metrics long the x axis for say a given item or sum of all items.

I've created measures using CALCULATE to filter by the rating but when I try and plot these my only option in power view is a clustered column graph where the x axis is the rating and the legend is the metrics.

I also created another small table with a single column of R0, R1 and R2 but can only link that to one metric column whereas I need it to link to all of them.

I think it's potentially a many to many mapping issue and have found a lot of links covering bridge tables and the magic CALCULATE function.

However as I'm trying to map values in a column to several other columns it doesn't seem to quite fit the many to many problem or if it does I can't see it.

I feel like what I'm after should be quite simple but I either end up with all my metric columns being made to show identical values or there's loads of cross filtering that I don't want. The "ratings" for each metric are essentially independent and I don't want to combine them in any way.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if my solution is in the links I've listed above then I'd really appreciate a bit of help with seeing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better inline images, links are discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for changing that - I didn't seem to be able to add them inline as it's my first post (i received a message about needing 10 points???) I also realised that I removed the links to the many-many articles I found as i wasn't allowed those either for the same reason. Therefore my last sentence doesn't really make sense but hopefully the rest of it does.